# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') when using MUI dat picker

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

After setting up my Form.js file I decided to add Mui's date picker but i keep getting the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

i've tried searching around and console logging my date picker value and everything seems to be running fine except for when i set state to the date selected

```
class Form extends React.Component {

state={
    volunteerName: '',
    seniorName: '',
    Date: '',
    Time: '',
    phoneNumber: ''
};

change = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};

onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
        volunteerName: '',
        seniorName: '',
        Date: '',
        Time: '',
        phoneNumber: ''
    })
}

render() {
    return(
        <form align='center' style={{marginTop: 45}}>
         <TextField name='volunteerName' id="outlined-basic" label="Volunteer Name" variant="outlined" value={this.state.volunteerName} onChange={e => this.change(e)} />
         <br/>
         <TextField name='seniorName' id="outlined-basic" label="Senior Name" variant="outlined" value={this.state.seniorName} onChange={e => this.change(e)} />
         <br/>   
         <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} name='date' id="outlined-basic" label="Date" variant="outlined">
         <DatePicker
            label="Date"
            value={this.state.Date}
            inputFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"
            onChange={e => this.change(e)}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />   
         </LocalizationProvider>   
         <br/>
         <TextField name='Time' id="outlined-basic" label="Time" variant="outlined" value={this.state.Time} onChange={e => this.change(e)} />
         <br/>   
         <TextField name='phoneNumber' id="outlined-basic" label="Phone Number" variant="outlined" value={this.state.phoneNumber} onChange={e => this.change(e)} />  
         <br/> 
         <Button variant="contained" onClick={async () => {
            const response = await fetch('/add_calls', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
            })

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('response worked')
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to read the `name` property when `e.target` is undefined. What does your console log statement inside the `change` function output?

Comment: ""2022-06-22T06:09:41.000Z"" is what it logs so that date picker seems to be working fine but changing the state is raising some issues

Answer (score 1):

your `e.target` is `undefined`. please check if your `DatePicker`passes `e.target` when `onChange` is called.